# finding items in one list that don't exist in others

Tags: c#, list

All the following are generic lists 
I have listA
and I have 4 other lists (list1, list2, list3, and list4)

How do I return items that exist in ListA, but don't exist in any of the other 4 lists?
i.e. if it exists in list1 or list2 or list3 or list4, I don't want to return it.

Comment: Have you used linq? Where is your code?

Comment: [How to: Find the Set Difference Between Two Lists (LINQ)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397894.aspx)

Comment: I would try using LINQ.

Answer (score 1):

As was commented above this is basically a set difference. The twist is that the subtracted set consists of several collections. You need to remove either the union of them, or remove them one at a time.
If you don't care about performance but look only for simplicity of implementation, use Linq:

```
var result = ListA
    .Except(list1)
    .Except(list2)
    .Except(list3)
    .Except(list4);
```

Comment: what if I am searching based on an item's property? let's say my lists are of type vehicle, and I want to search based on vehicle.color

Comment: @IsaacBok See my update, it handles exactly this case.

Answer (score -1):

something like this using Linq [`Any`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb534972(v=vs.100).aspx):

```
var result = ListA.Where(x => !(
        list1.Any(y => x.MyProp == y.MyProp) || 
        list2.Any(y => x.MyProp == y.MyProp) || 
        list3.Any(y => x.MyProp == y.MyProp) || 
        list4.Any(y => x.MyProp == y.MyProp)));
```

Alternativly you may also override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` from `object` to compare your properties.